# Migrating webpack 3 to webpack 4

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to update webpack's version from 3 to version 4. I'm using ReactJS's template from VS ASP.NET Core Web Apps

[template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5gcJ.jpg)

I can't find information how can I do that.

Comment: I think this [webpack-demo](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) can help you with configuring **webpack-4** with **react**

Comment: Thanks @Carloluis

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation and migration guide for webpack 4 have not been finished, yet](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/issues/1706). You can either wait for the webpack contributors to finish it or use the information from the [release notes](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v4.0.0).

There is also a [work-in-progress version of the migration to webpack 4 guide](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/blob/dc072b6512610893290b25882fb46efe0493bbb5/src/content/guides/migrating.md).